# Is there anything terrible about setting ft_min_word_len=2 for MySQL FULLTEXT searches?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

In order to do FULLTEXT searches on 2-letter phrases such as "**PR** Manager" and "**MS** Word", I have added *ft_min_word_len=2* to the MySQL config file (/etc/mysql/my.cnf).

Is there anything particularly wrong with doing this? Will it reduce performance? Will it prevent scaling to large datasets?

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your version of mysql? Is this config still supported for latest mysql too?

Answer (score 2):

No, it may only increase your full text dictionary size but won't have a particular impact on search performance.

Answer (score 2):

All two-letter combinations will have to be indexed, which will increase the size of your search indexes and slow down the indexing process.  It should have small impact on the speed of searches itself.  You may also run into more words becoming stop-words and becoming unsearchable.  It's unlikely "PR" and "MS" would become stop-words, but "IT" is very likely, given that FTS is normally case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-min-word-len.html), min_word_len will only reduce your index size.

FYI, **[min_infix_len](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-min-infix-len.html)** is a different story. Assuming 2.0.1-beta or higher, Sphinx is using [dict=keywords](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-dict.html).

There are two things to know:

- As soon as you specify min_infix_len, Sphinx will store suffixes of words to allow infix/suffix search.
- Reducing the min_infix_len does not reduce the index size (as it used to with the old **crc** index). This is because all the word suffixes still need to be stored. As such, min_infix_len only reduces *results*, and not index size.

Comment: Tom was asking about the MySQL Fulltext, not Sphinx.

Comment: Huh. Wherever did I get that idea... Thanks for pointing that out!